# Найти четвертое слово в файле и заменить его вторую букву на «k»

Tags: python

Как мне найти четвертое слово в файле и заменить его вторую букву на «k». в python

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Открыть файл. Прочитать его. Разбить на слова и итерироваться по ним, печатая результат. Дойдя до 4-го слова поменять в нём вторую букву перед печатью. Всё. Или нужно результат записать обратно в файл? Тогда не печатать, а писать в файл.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если надо просто вывести:

```
test=open('ваш файл')
r=test.read().split()
test.close()
a=r[3]
r[3]=a.replace(a[1], 'k', 1)
print(' '.join(r))
```

А если перезаписать в файл:

```
test=open('ваш файл')
r=test.read().split()
test.close()
a=r[3]
r[3]=a.replace(a[1], 'k', 1)
test=open('ваш файл', 'w')
test.write(' '.join(r))
test.close()
```

Comment: Лучше не использовать для таких вещей `replace`, подумайте, что будет, если в слове первые две буквы будут одинаковыми. Вероятность этого не велика, но она есть. Лучше использовать `replace` только для случаев, когда нужно поменять все вхождения, параметр `count` не панацея.